# 1004 Read-Only Error when Opening Closed Workbooks in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

To give context to the problem that I'm facing - keep in mind I'm a relative novice - I am attempting to write a code that will open and then close a series of workbooks all contained within a folder, ultimately in order to update a number of VLookups on the master data sheet (since to update them, I believe the dependents need to be open).

Right now, I'm simply attempting to do this for one of the files which I can then go through and do for the rest of the folder. When I do attempt to open the file though, I get the "Run-Time Error 1004" with the message "Excel cannot access 'FolderName'. The document may be read-only or encrypted"

The code I'm using is:

```
sub openevery_v2()
' openevery_v2 Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+O

' Dim diaFolder As FileDialog <-- Ideally the user would use a dialog box to select the folder
' Dim Fname As String
' Dim originalWB As Workbook
' Set originalWB = ThisWorkbook
' originalWB.Save
' Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
' diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
' diaFolder.Show
' Fname = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

Fname = "C:\FolderPath"
Openr = Dir(Fname + "Filename.xlsm")
Workbooks.Open (Fname)

End Sub
```

I've tried to change the settings of the folder from non-read only, but I don't think that is the issue at hand.

Has anyone run through a similar issue or can think of a solution to this particular issue? Alternatively, if there is a better way to think through this challenge, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are so many lines of code commented out in your example?  Especially the line defining Fname.

Comment: @TMH8885, I think the OP is trying to provide a minimum case for showing his error. At least, that's what I would have done...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to open a file named `c:\FolderPathFilename.xlsm`. Unless that file exists in the root of your `C:` drive, you'll get errors.

This may be more of what you're after:

```
Fname = "C:\FolderPath\"
Openr = Dir(Fname & "Filename.xlsm")
Workbooks.Open (Fname)
```

**Notice:**

1. the `\` added to the end of `Fname`.
2. The `+` is replaced with a `&`. VBA uses `&` for concatenation.

Of course, your code sample does seem to be a very cut-down version of what you're really executing, so that may not be the problem in your real code.